# WSO2 Single Logout implementation

Tags: single-sign-on, wso2, logout, saml-2.0

I'm trying to implement WSO2 Single Logout functionality in my java webapp.
And I cannot understand this thing:

I set SAML Single Logout option for 2 my Issuers.
Then I call logout for first Service Provider (SP), IdP redirects it to some logout url with SAML Response, SP gets this request and invalidates http session.

Second SP also gets request from IdP with SAML Response, but http session in this request is a session between IdP and SP, and I need to invalidate session between web browser and SP. How can I get this session?

Comment: What are you using of SP software at the webapp?

Comment: Ok, so you are just handling all the SAML XML manually?

Comment: I use  openSAML in SamlConsumerManager from this example - [http://wso2.org/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to manually keep track over what http session is associated with what sessionSAMLIndex(you get this in the assertion at login). Perhaps `Map<String, HttpSession>`

The LogoutRequest contains the session index. When you get the LogoutRequest, you find the http session and invalidate it.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it, but was hoping that there is another way :)

Comment: @Stefan can you please give some details about finding the session using the index and also what happens to the cookies

Comment: @MayankSharma please ask this in a new question.